# Error en el servidortras actualizar docker

Tags: php, docker, apache2

yo tengo un servidor con php en un contenedor docker, el cual funcionaba súper bien hasta que actualicé docker.

edit: (Nota: estoy usando windows 11, y al ejecutar el proyecto con xampp no hay ningún problema)

Este es el código que está en el docuemento "Dockerfile"

```
FROM php:8-apache
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Este es el comando para construir mis imágenes:
`docker build -t php:prueba .`

Y este es el comando para ejecutarlo en un contenedor
`docker run -p 80:80 -d --name cienciex-php_prueba2 cienciex-php:prueba`

Pero al ingresar al navegador me encuentro conel siguiente error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

la actualización fué realizada el día de ayer: 08/mar/2022

ente error se da incluso ejecutando viejos contenedores los cuales funcionaban con total normalidad.

Al mirar los "losgs" del sontenedor, ento es lo que me encuentro:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Thu Mar 10 02:20:46.347622 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) PHP/8.1.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Mar 10 02:20:46.347662 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:15.533521 2022] [core:alert] [pid 18] [client 172.17.0.1:33032] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:15.533837 2022] [core:alert] [pid 19] [client 172.17.0.1:33036] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:15.829523 2022] [core:alert] [pid 20] [client 172.17.0.1:33040] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:15.850580 2022] [core:alert] [pid 21] [client 172.17.0.1:33044] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/cursos

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:17.739133 2022] [core:alert] [pid 22] [client 172.17.0.1:33052] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:17.865479 2022] [core:alert] [pid 18] [client 172.17.0.1:33054] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/cursos

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:15 +0000] "GET /cursos HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "http://localhost/cursos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:17 +0000] "GET /cursos HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:02:21:17 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "http://localhost/cursos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:03:38:50 +0000] "GET /cursos HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

172.17.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2022:03:38:50 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "http://localhost/cursos" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

[Thu Mar 10 02:21:46.999223 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Thu Mar 10 03:38:36.499869 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) PHP/8.1.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Mar 10 03:38:36.499924 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

[Thu Mar 10 03:38:50.792710 2022] [core:alert] [pid 18] [client 172.17.0.1:33106] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[Thu Mar 10 03:38:50.936702 2022] [core:alert] [pid 19] [client 172.17.0.1:33108] /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/cursos

[Thu Mar 10 03:39:00.044969 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[Thu Mar 10 03:39:30.329856 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) PHP/8.1.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Mar 10 03:39:30.329902 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Prueba entonces revisando los logs de ese servidor con `docker nombre_conainer logs`. Tambien puedes entrar con `docker run -it nombre_contenedor bash` a una sesión ssh dentro del contenedor y dale cat, vi o lo que tengas en ese contenedor para ver los logs de ese apache. Edita tu pregunta con lo que veas allí

Comment: Tiene pinta de que hay un .htaccess que no funciona bien. ¿Actualizaste docker o actualizaste la imagen que estás usando? Puede que el htaccess tenga caracteres fin de línea windows CR+LF y en tu contenedor linux eso genere problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el mensaje de error `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'`, lo más probable es que no esté habilitado el módulo `mod_rewrite`:

```
FROM php:8-apache
# Habilitar mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064289/2412893) (en inglés):

> Don't forget to run your `docker-compose up` command with `--build` if you have already built the image previously, otherwise it will run the old image which may have not included the `RUN a2enmod rewrite` statement.

Básicamente: Si ya creaste previamente la imagen, debes volver a crearla con la opción `build`.

Ten en cuenta que esa respuesta es de hace 6 años y, seguramente, hubo cambios en la forma de construir las imágenes, por lo que tal vez sea el mismo comando que has usado antes: `docker build -t php:prueba`

Comment: Hola, ya apliqué tu consejo, pero me sale otro error con "mysqli" ya que el motor ya no busca la base de datos en el localhost, sino en: "/var/www/html/"

Comment: @JavierVergara, ¿Podrías ser más específico, por favor? ¿Qué mensaje de error obtienes y dónde?

Comment: Ahora me sale como si el .htaccess no existiera, asi que no enruta